# FMX grid header lines color

Tags: delphi, grid, firemonkey

I'm looking for a way to change the color of the lines in the **header** of an FMX grid. I have the following code to change the color of the lines in the grid itself, using an interposer:

```
type
  TStringGrid = class(FMX.Grid.TStringGrid)
  protected
    procedure ApplyStyle; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    StringColumn1: TStringColumn;
    StringColumn2: TStringColumn;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{ TStringGrid }

procedure TStringGrid.ApplyStyle;
var
  LLineFill: TBrushObject;
begin
  if FindStyleResource<TBrushObject>('LineFill', LLineFill) then
    LLineFill.Brush.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Orange;
  inherited;
end;
```

Which results in this:

[image]

But as can be seen, that just changes the color of the grid lines, **not** the header lines (which are still grey). Someone else suggested modifying the `headeritemstyle` (in code or at design-time) however that's a `TButtonStyleObject`, so there doesn't seem to be any relevant properties for that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The style engine seems to neglect the headers totally (up until and including Delphi 10.4 CE, I don't know about later versions). But you can of course draw the header yourself. However, if your application supports several different styles, and you want to adapt your header drawing to currently selected style, it may become quite involved with different colors etc.

Also you don't need to subclass the grid in order to use a style, for those parts of the grid that the style supports. Just select the grid, right click on it with the mouse and select "Edit custom style". The selected style will become a part of your form.

Anyway, to answer your question, use the `OnDrawColumnHeader()` event as follows.

```
procedure TForm4.StringGrid1DrawColumnHeader(Sender: TObject;
  const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF);
var
  ABrush: TStrokeBrush;
  ARectF: TRectF;
begin
  // fill
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Lavender;
  Canvas.FillRect(Bounds, 0, 0, [], 1);

  // draw rect, actually only bottom and right side of current header cell
  ABrush := TStrokeBrush.Create( TBrushKind.Solid , TAlphaColorRec.Red);
  try
    Canvas.DrawRectSides(Bounds, 0, 0, [], 1, [TSide.Bottom, TSide.Right], ABrush, TCornerType.Round);

    // Draw header text
    ARectF := Bounds;
    ARectF.Left := ARectF.Left + 4;
    Canvas.Font.Size := 15;
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
    Canvas.FillText(ARectF, Column.Header , False, 1, [] , TTextAlign.Leading);
  finally
    ABrush.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I used `TAlphaColorRec.Lavender` as fill color and `TAlphaColorRec.Red` as line color for the header cells.

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: To save having to create a whole other question, any idea on how to change the border color? (i.e. the extreme outside of the grid).. I'm stuck.. again.